# My CSS wrapper is overlapping in height

Tags: css, wrapper, css-grid

```
@media screen  and (max-width: 1000px) /* Tablet */ {
  #wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 100% 1fr 1fr 100%;
  grid-template-areas: "meny"
                       "bakgrunn"
                       "content"
                       "footer";
  grid-gap: 0px;
  font-family: lato light;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

So in my tablet version my wrapper just exceeds my footer and gives me a blank white space, i have tried giving it a max height but then it just wraps my entire content aswell. Any solutions?

Comment: Show the wrapper html layout.

Comment: Try `min-height: 100vh`. Percentage heights can be tricky.